# Google SEO vs AJAX

Tags: ajax, seo

At this URL (http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html) Google says:

"You can create a static version of your pages offline, as is the current practice. For example, many applications draw content from a database that is then rendered by the browser. Instead, you may create a separate HTML page for each AJAX URL."

Let's say you have a section of your page for displaying paged content, such as notifications. When you click "3" it shows you the 3rd page of notifications, but uses AJAX to dynamically update that part of the page. And let's say that data gets retrieved from my.domain.com/notifications/3

I was told that Google would ban you for providing a different view of that data using the same URL for non-AJAX requests. So if you go to my.domain.com/notifications/3 directly (not via AJAX) and return an HTML document showing those notifications, you could get banned.

Is that accurate? What are the rules/limits as far as providing different formats/views of the same data? Could I get away with returning the notifications as JSON or XML for AJAX requests, but return HTML for non-AJAX requests so it can be crawled and viewed directly by users?

Comment: You can do this now: complete example: https://github.com/kubrickology/Logical-escaped_fragment

Answer (score 1):

As long as you follow Google's instructions you will be OK.

A different view of the same data is fine. It's if you try and provide different data to robots.